# Starling Image change texture looks like lag and blurry

Tags: actionscript-3, textures, lag, starling-framework

In my project I implement the animation by change the bitmap's bitmapdata, now I try to use starling.

I try to change Image's texture each frame, the animation looks good when stand there. But when the animation moves, it looks like lag and blurry, and the fps never down.

The textures for the Image are in different size, so I called Image's readjustSize method when set texture. So I guess maybe cause the problem. I try same size textures, but the result  is same.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use Movie Clip instead. If you want the control over playspeed, particular frames or anything else - it is there.

http://wiki.starling-framework.org/manual/movie_clips